# drop elements of a level of a multi-level index pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

In the following DataFrame there are a 2-level MultiIndex, namely `city` and `date`:

```
                 temp
                count
city date            
SFO  2014-05-31    31
     2014-06-30    30
     2014-07-31    31
     2014-08-31    31
     2014-09-30    30
YYZ  2014-05-31    31
     2014-06-30    30
     2014-07-31    31
     2014-08-31    31
     2014-09-30    30
```

I want to drop `2014-05-31` and `2014-09-30` from the date level.

How do I do this?

**Comment:** To build the DataFrame -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {('temp', 'count'): {('SFO', Timestamp('2014-05-31 00:00:00')): 31,
                         ('SFO', Timestamp('2014-06-30 00:00:00')): 30,
                         ('SFO', Timestamp('2014-07-31 00:00:00')): 31,
                         ('SFO', Timestamp('2014-08-31 00:00:00')): 31,
                         ('SFO', Timestamp('2014-09-30 00:00:00')): 30,
                         ('YYZ', Timestamp('2014-05-31 00:00:00')): 31,
                         ('YYZ', Timestamp('2014-06-30 00:00:00')): 30,
                         ('YYZ', Timestamp('2014-07-31 00:00:00')): 31,
                         ('YYZ', Timestamp('2014-08-31 00:00:00')): 31,
                         ('YYZ', Timestamp('2014-09-30 00:00:00')): 30}}
).rename_axis(['city','date'])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give [drop](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.drop.html) a specific `level`:

```
In[4]: df.drop([Timestamp('2014-05-31'),Timestamp('2014-09-30')],level=1)
Out[4]: 
                 temp
                count
city date            
SFO  2014-06-30    30
     2014-07-31    31
     2014-08-31    31
YYZ  2014-06-30    30
     2014-07-31    31
     2014-08-31    31
```